# Access the Id of the postCreator in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mean

**Update**: *From some research, i cant render a value whose value is continuously changed by Observable in the subscribe() function.  How do I then move the "onUserNameClick" function in subscribe and still have the functionality of redirecting t user profile only when I click on username*

Am learning how to code by building a job board with a community, 3 months in. Am trying to access the postCreator id, and use it to redirect to user profile. What am I doing wrong? Can't console log it.

```js
 ngOnInit() {
  this.postId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
  this.postsService.getPost(this.postId)
        .subscribe(selectPostData => {
          this.post = {
            postId: selectPostData.data._id,
            postTitle: selectPostData.data.postTitle,
            postContent: selectPostData.data.postContent,
            postVote: selectPostData.data.postVote,
            postCreator: selectPostData.data.postCreator,
            postCreatedAt: selectPostData.data.createdAt,
            image: selectPostData.data.image
          };
         // console.log(this.post)
          this.userId = this.post.postCreator._id
        });
console.log(this.userId)
  }
  // getCreatorInfo(){
  //   this.post.postCreator
  //   console.log(this.post)
  // }

  onUserNameClick (userId: any){
    this.router.navigate(['/user-profile', userId])
```

```html
 <a
            href="/user-profile"
            class="post-page__creator"
            (click)="onUserNameClick(post.postCreator._id)"
            >by
            <span>
              {{ post.postCreator.userName }}
            </span>
          </a>
```

Comment: Did yu try to console.log(selectPostData) to see the data

Comment: Your ```console.log(this.userId)``` should be in the subscribe() function.

Comment: I can see the data with both console.log(this.post) and console.log(selectPostData) only when it's inside the subscribe.

Comment: @CharlieV agree and that works, but how do I get the postCreator Id outside subscribe() function and set it to be a userId?

Comment: What does the following show in console: '''console.log("Creator:",selectPost.postCreator," ID:",selectPost.postCreator._id)'' if you add that to the subscribe() function?

Comment: @CharlieV I had to modify to console.log("Creator:",selectPostData.data.postCreator," ID:",selectPostData.data.postCreator._id) and it gives me the postCreator data and the Id

Comment: You've added a comment: from research. What is exactly your problem? It seems that this code runs OK and gives you the ID of the user. Did you share the code that is giving you problems or are you encountering something else completely?

Comment: @CharlieV Code runs fine. What I want to do is extract the postCreator id and use it outside the subscribe () function and in the ---> onUserNameClick (userId: any){
    this.router.navigate(['/user-profile', userId])} ----> function.

Comment: Is your HTML part of the component? Then you have access to all public attributes of your component in your HTML. And the HTML you shared should work. If this is not the case then you really have to share more of your code and setup.

Comment: Thank you @CharlieV, I figured it out. I dnt need the use the  href="/user-profile" in my html..... this.router.navigate(['/user-profile', userId]) in my component brings me to the page I want without the href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can try this way**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="post-page__creator" 
(click)="onUserNameClick(post.postCreator._id)">by
    <span>
        {{ post.postCreator.userName }}
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the href from my html seems to be working. I guess it was somewhat redundant to redirect to user profile form html component.htm and also navigate to user profile onClickUserName in my component.ts

```html
<a class="post-page__creator" (click)="onUserNameClick(post.postCreator._id)">by
            <span>
              {{ post.postCreator.userName }}
            </span>
 </a>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.postId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
  this.postsService.getPost(this.postId)
    .subscribe(selectPostData => {
      this.post = {
        postId: selectPostData.data._id,
        postTitle: selectPostData.data.postTitle,
        postContent: selectPostData.data.postContent,
        postVote: selectPostData.data.postVote,
        postCreator: selectPostData.data.postCreator,
        postCreatedAt: selectPostData.data.createdAt,
        image: selectPostData.data.image
      };
      // console.log(this.post)
      this.userId = this.post.postCreator._id
    });
  console.log(this.userId)
}
onUserNameClick(userId: any) {
  this.router.navigate(['/user-profile', userId])
}
```

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.postId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId');
  this.postsService.getPost(this.postId)
        .subscribe(selectPostData => {
          this.post = {
            postId: selectPostData.data._id,
            postTitle: selectPostData.data.postTitle,
            postContent: selectPostData.data.postContent,
            postVote: selectPostData.data.postVote,
            postCreator: selectPostData.data.postCreator,
            postCreatedAt: selectPostData.data.createdAt,
            image: selectPostData.data.image
          };
          console.log(this.post)
          this.userId = this.post.postCreator._id
        });
   
  }

  onUserNameClick (userId: any){
    this.router.navigate(['/user-profile', userId])}
```

```html
<a
            class="post-page__creator"
            (click)="onUserNameClick(post.postCreator._id)"
            >by
            <span>
              {{ post.postCreator.userName }}
            </span>
 </a>
```